# Bulk Copy Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am attempting to use the SQL Database Migration Wizard

[SQL Database Migration Wizard](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)

to upload a table from my local SQL Express instance to an Azure database.

The table was given to me as a flat file and has 1.8 million records in it.

Azure wouldn't allow me to upload this table as it did not have a primary key index. So, I added a new field called trevId and made it a primary key...

my table create script looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Written_Premiums](
[Client Account Number] [varchar](8) NULL,
....
[Period] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
[trevId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Written_Premiums] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[trevId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

But, for a reason I don't understand, it fails to upload with the following error after it has uploaded 1372000 lines of the table...:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = 23000, NativeError = 2627
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Written_Premiums'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Written_Premiums'. The duplicate key value is (1).
SQLState = 01000, NativeError = 3621
Warning = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated.
BCP copy in failed
```

I had about 20 tables to upload besides this one. I added the index manually to all the other tables and they uploaded without error.

The only difference is that this table is by far the largest of the tables I am attempting to upload...

Can anyone make any suggestions to what might be going wrong please?

EDIT: forgot to mention that the wizard had created a fresh clean table so there can be no chance of there already being data in there...

EDIT: When I look in the rows that have been successfully added there is indeed a record with a trevId = 1... why would it be trying to upload another record with the same id?

Comment: Are you sure the message isn't actually correct? Does the table *already* have a row with trevId=1? What does the format file for BCP look like?

Comment: sorry, I should have said, the Wizard process had created an empty table with no records in it... I have the .dat file but it's 500mb in size - is that where I would find the format?

Comment: For now try changing IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF to on.Data must  be having duplicates for sure,which you can check after loading